# Left Join instead of Not Exists in SQL Db2

Tags: sql, db2, left-join

I'm currently revise a SQL Query of mine due to bad performance.

So the the query Checks table A and B, and reports in case something is missing on table B.
Currently I'm working with a solution using "Where not exists", which leads that both tables have to be selected entirely. This leading to bad performance

```
SELECT A.DBNAME,                                     
       A.TSNAME,                                     
       VARCHAR(A.PARTITION)                          
FROM DUMMY.TABLEONE A WHERE NOT EXISTS          
   (SELECT B.DBNAME                                  
          ,B.TSNAME                                  
          ,B.LOGICAL_PART                            
          ,B.ICDATE                                  
          ,B.ICTYPE                                  
           FROM DUMMY.TABLETWO B                     
   WHERE B.DBNAME = A.DBNAME AND B.TSNAME = A.TSNAME 
   AND   A.PARTITION = B.LOGICAL_PART                
   AND   B.ICTYPE = 'F'                              
   AND   B.ICDATE > CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS);
```

This Query gives me the correct result set, but the performance is pretty poor.

I tried to re write it as left Join:

```
SELECT A.DBNAME,                                       
       A.TSNAME,                                       
       VARCHAR(A.PARTITION)                            
FROM DUMMY.TABLEONE A                             
LEFT JOIN                                              
DUMMY.TABLETWO B                                       
ON A.DBNAME = B.DBNAME AND                             
   A.TSNAME = B.TSNAME AND                             
   A.PARTITION = B.LOGICAL_PART                        
   WHERE B.DBNAME IS NULL                              
   OR  (A.DBNAME = B.DBNAME AND                        
        A.TSNAME = B.TSNAME AND                        
        A.PARTITION = B.LOGICAL_PART AND               
        B.ICDATE > CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS);
```

But as the entries on table B are not getting deleted, I get far too many results.
I only want to retrieve entries on table A where's no corresponding entry within the last seven days on table B.
The old entries have to be kept, otherwise I would implement a House-keeping solution.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider indexing the `TABLETWO` table as follows:

```sql
CREATE INDEX tt_idx ON DUMMY.TABLETWO (DBNAME, TSNAME, LOGICAL_PART, ICTYPE, ICDATE);
```

This should allow the exists logic to execute much faster, for every record in the `TABLEONE` table.  Also, you can simplify the exists syntax as follows:

```sql
SELECT A.DBNAME, A.TSNAME, VARCHAR(A.PARTITION)
FROM DUMMY.TABLEONE A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM DUMMY.TABLETWO B
    WHERE B.DBNAME = A.DBNAME AND
          B.TSNAME = A.TSNAME AND
          A.PARTITION = B.LOGICAL_PART AND
          B.ICTYPE = 'F' AND
          B.ICDATE > CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS
);
```

Comment: Hi Tim
Thanks for your quick response. Of course, an index will increase the performance extremely.. I don't know why I didn't think of that.